# Forecasting a time series with weights

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'd like to forecast (or predict) a time series with weights.

The following works using the regular `l`inear `m`odelling techniques of `lm` by applying a (sigmoidal) weight distribution to the input data, essentially weighing the latter data points more heavily than the former:

```
library("stats")
lm.weight.function <- function(x) {10 / (1 + exp(-x))} # Sigmoidal
lm.weights <- lapply(seq(-13, 14, length.out = 27), lm.weight.function)
lm.input <- as.data.frame(c(23957, 46771, 60767, 73284, 60296, 73122, 78304, 87154, 80459, 76885, 56479, 18809, 13453, 13951, 25140, 12035, 11920, 20683, 30357, 35019, 37732, 46150, 47856, 41931, 20985, 32526, 27283))
lm.input <- cbind(1:27, lm.input)
colnames(lm.input) <- c('x', 'y')
lm.model <- lm(formula = y ~ log(x), data = lm.input, weights = unlist(lm.weights))
predict.input <- as.data.frame(28:55)
colnames(predict.input) <- 'x'
predict.model <- predict(lm.model, predict.input)
plot(1:(27+28), c(lm.input$y, predict.model), type = 'l', xlab = 'x', ylab = 'y')
```

[image]

Now I wish to do the same using the `forecast` package. However, I'm having difficulty specifying the `weights`:

```
library("forecast")
ts.weight.function <- function(x) {10 / (1 + exp(-x))} # Sigmoidal
ts.weights <- as.data.frame(lapply(seq(-13, 14, length.out = 27), ts.weight.function))
colnames(ts.weights) <- 'trend'
ts.input <- ts(c(23957, 46771, 60767, 73284, 60296, 73122, 78304, 87154, 80459, 76885, 56479, 18809, 13453, 13951, 25140, 12035, 11920, 20683, 30357, 35019, 37732, 46150, 47856, 41931, 20985, 32526, 27283), frequency = 1)
ts.model <- tslm(formula = ts.input ~ log(trend), weights = unlist(ts.weights))
```

The above prints an error:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : 
  ..1 used in an incorrect context, no ... to look in
```

How can I use `tslm` to forecast a time series with weights?

Comment: Did you try `traceback`? That's an odd error, but what it seems like is that there's a function inside another function, the inside function is being passed the argument `...`, but the function it's inside doesn't have a `...` argument to pass. My guess is tslm is somehow calling the wrong thing, or is being told to call something that it doesn't expect to call.

Comment: You get a similar error when you try something like `bad = function(x) plot(...); bad(rnorm(5))` which throws `Error in bad(rnorm(5)) : '...' used in an incorrect context`.

Comment: Super delayed, but check out these two articles for help: - http://developer.r-project.org/nonstandard-eval.pdf - https://developer.r-project.org/model-fitting-functions.html

Comment: Your idea (weight the later data points more heavily) is essentially  exponential smoothing.  Try the `ets` function in the forecast package— I've found that the function is very easy to use and often gives good results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is an issue with `lm`.

```
wrapper = function(formula,...)
  lm(formula=formula,...)
x=(1:27)
wrapper(ts.input~x,weights=ts.weights)
```

produces the exact same error. If you read the source code to `tslm`, you'll find that `lm` is called in more or less the sam way.

I found [here](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/dot-dot-dot-as-an-actual-argument-tp1561513p1561546.html) that `..1` means the first argument included in `...`, which in this case is the only argument, `weights`. It suggests that this kind of error could be caused because argument being passed doesn't exist in the environment from which the function is being called. You can see this behavior with `wrapper(ts.input~x,weights=foo)` if you don't have any object called `foo`.

Running a traceback on `wrapper(ts.input~x,weights=ts.weights)` reveals:

```
8 eval(expr, envir, enclos) 
7 eval(extras, data, env) 
6 model.frame.default(formula = formula, weights = ..1, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) 
5 stats::model.frame(formula = formula, weights = ..1, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) 
4 eval(expr, envir, enclos) 
3 eval(mf, parent.frame()) 
2 lm(formula = formula, ...) 
1 wrapper(ts.input ~ x, weights = ts.weights)
```

And in the source code of `lm`,

```
mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
m <- match(c("formula", "data", "subset", "weights", "na.action", 
    "offset"), names(mf), 0L)
mf <- mf[c(1L, m)]
mf$drop.unused.levels <- TRUE
mf[[1L]] <- quote(stats::model.frame)
mf <- eval(mf, parent.frame())
if (method == "model.frame") 
    return(mf)
```

which suggests that the call to `model.frame` is picking up on the `...` in a strange way.

So I decided to try it without `...`:

```
wrapper = function(formula,weights)
  lm(formula=formula,weights=weights)
x=(1:27)
wrapper(ts.input~x,weights=ts.weights)
```

which produced

```
 Error in model.frame.default(formula = formula, weights = weights, drop.unused.levels = TRUE) :
```

invalid type (closure) for variable '(weights)'

A closure, of course, is a function in R. Which can mean only one thing... `weights` is already a function in the global environment. Indeed, `?weights` reveals that it's ironically the extractor function for model weights. It's a no-brainer that it gets search priority over local variables. So I changed the argument names (since `formula` is also a function):

```
wrapper = function(fm,ws){
  print(ws)
  lm(formula=fm,weights=ws)
}
x=(1:27)
wrapper(fm=ts.input~x,ws=ts.weights)
```

now produces

```
 [1] 2.260324e-05 6.385091e-05 1.803683e-04 5.094997e-04 1.439136e-03 4.064300e-03
 [7] 1.147260e-02 3.234087e-02 9.082267e-02 2.523791e-01 6.815483e-01 1.712317e+00
[13] 3.685455e+00 6.224593e+00 8.232410e+00 9.293615e+00 9.737984e+00 9.905650e+00
[19] 9.966395e+00 9.988078e+00 9.995776e+00 9.998504e+00 9.999471e+00 9.999813e+00
[25] 9.999934e+00 9.999977e+00 9.999992e+00

 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'ws' not found
```

And if you run `traceback` you still get the same issue with `model.frame`. So I'm completely baffled. My only conclusion is that a) it has nothing to do with `tslm` or time series analysis, and b) the problem lies somewhere in the way arguments are passed around inside `lm`.

That probably doesn't help you at all, but hopefully at least someone can come along and explain what's going on here. My provisional answer to your actual question of how to use weights in `tslm` is that you can't.

Comment: +1 have the same problem in another package (CHAID).. how did you get this resolved?

Comment: @Ruslan I never figured it out. You might want to post it on one of the R-help mailing lists since, again, it seems like a problem deep inside `lm`.

Comment: My traceback shows problem function (x = NULL, max.lines = getOption("deparse.max.lines"))  -- different from yours, but symptoms are exactly the same. Thanks

Comment: I deleted weights parameter and it started working.. bummer.